# SSH – Force Command execution on login even without Shell

Tags: ssh, sshd

I am creating a restricted user without shell for port forwarding only and I need to execute a script on login via pubkey, even if the user is connected via `ssh -N user@host` which doesn't asks SSH server for a shell.

The script should warn admin on connections authenticated with pubkey, so the user connecting shouldn't be able to skip the execution of the script (e.g., by connecting with `ssh -N`).

I have tried to no avail:

- Setting the command at `/etc/ssh/sshrc`.
- Using command="COMMAND" in `.ssh/authorized_keys` (man authorized_keys)
- Setting up a script with the command as user's shell. (`chsh -s /sbin/myscript.sh USERNAME`)
- Matching user in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` like:

  `Match User MYUSERNAME
  ForceCommand "/sbin/myscript.sh"`

All work when user asks for shell, but if logged only for port forwarding and no shell (`ssh -N`) it doesn't work.

Comment: ForceCommand runs without a pty unless one is requested. Fix your script so that it doesn't require a pty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need to run a script you can rely on `pam_exec`.

Basically you reference the script you need to run in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` configuration:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/script.sh
```

After some testing you may want to change `optional` to `required`.

Please refer to this answer "[bash - How do I set up an email alert when a ssh login is successful? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/448602)" for a similar request.

Indeed in the script only a limited subset on the environment variables is available:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
PAM_USER=bitnami
PAM_RHOST=192.168.1.17
PAM_TYPE=open_session
PAM_SERVICE=sshd
PAM_TTY=ssh
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
PWD=/
```

If you want to get the user info from `authorized_keys` this script could be helpful:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get user from authorized_keys
# pam_exec_login.sh
# * [ssh - What is the SHA256 that comes on the sshd entry in auth.log? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/888281/what-is-the-sha256-that-comes-on-the-sshd-entry-in-auth-log)
# * [bash - How to get all fingerprints for .ssh/authorized_keys(2) file - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/413231/how-to-get-all-fingerprints-for-ssh-authorized-keys2-file)

# Setup log
b=$(basename $0| cut -d. -f1)
log="/tmp/${b}.log"

function timeStamp () {
  echo "$(date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S') ${HOSTNAME} $b[$$]:"
}

# Check if opening a remote session with sshd
if [ "${PAM_TYPE}" != "open_session" ] || [ $PAM_SERVICE != "sshd" ] || [ $PAM_RHOST == "::1" ]; then
  exit $PAM_SUCCESS
fi

# Get info from auth.log
authLogLine=$(journalctl -u ssh.service |tail -100 |grep "sshd\[${PPID}\]" |grep "${PAM_RHOST}")
echo ${authLogLine} >> ${log}

PAM_USER_PORT=$(echo ${authLogLine}| sed -r 's/.*port (.*) ssh2.*/\1/')
PAM_USER_SHA256=$(echo ${authLogLine}| sed -r 's/.*SHA256:(.*)/\1/')

# Get details from .ssh/authorized_keys
authFile="/home/${PAM_USER}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
PAM_USER_authorized_keys=""

while read l; do
  if [[ -n "$l" && "${l###}" = "$l" ]]; then
    authFileSHA256=$(ssh-keygen -l -f <(echo "$l"))
    if [[ "${authFileSHA256}" == *"${PAM_USER_SHA256}"* ]]; then
      PAM_USER_authorized_keys=$(echo ${authFileSHA256}| cut -d" " -f3)
      break
    fi
  fi
done < ${authFile}

if [[ -n ${PAM_USER_authorized_keys} ]]
then
  echo "$(timeStamp) Local user: ${PAM_USER}, authorized_keys user: ${PAM_USER_authorized_keys}" >> ${log}
else
  echo "$(timeStamp) WARNING: no matching user in authorized_keys" >> ${log}
fi
```

Answer (score 22):

The [ForceCommand](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5#ForceCommand) option runs without a PTY unless the client requests one. As a result, you don't actually have a shell to execute scripts the way you might expect. In addition, the OpenSSH SSHD_CONFIG(5) man page clearly says:

> The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the -c option.

That means that if you've disabled the user's login shell, or set it to something like `/bin/false`, then ForceCommand can't work. Assuming that:

1. the user has a sensible shell defined,
2. that your target script is executable, and
3. that your script has an appropriate shebang line

then the following should work in your *global* sshd_config file once properly modified with the proper username and fully-qualified pathname to your custom script:

```
Match User foo
    ForceCommand /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: This works only if I don't use `ssh -N` flag to connect. But anyway you made me realize that is not possible to achieve this using sshd only... the script should warn on connections authenticated with pubkey, so the user connecting shouldn't be able to skip it using 'ssh -N'.

Answer (score 5):

I am the author of the OP; I came to the conclusion that what I need to achieve is not possible using SSH only to the date (`OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015`), but I found a great piece of software that uses encrypted SPAuthentication to open SSH port and it's new version (to the date of this post, it's GitHub master branch) has a feature to execute a command always that a user authorizates successfully.

## FWKNOP - Encrypted Single Packet Authorization

FWKNOP set iptables rules that allow access to given ports upon a single packet encrypted which is sent via UDP. Then after authorization it allow access for the authorized user for a given time, for example 30 seconds, closing the port after this, leaving the connection open.

### 1. To install on an Ubuntu linux:

**The current version (2.6.0-2.1build1) on Ubuntu repositories to the date still doesn't allow command execution on successful SPA; (please use 2.6.8 from GitHub instead)**

On client machine:

`sudo apt-get install fwknop-client`

On server side:

`sudo apt-get install fwknop-server`

Here is a tutorial on how to setup the client and server machines
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SinglePacketAuthorization

**Then**, after it is set up, on server side:

1. Edit `/etc/default/fwknop-server`
2. Change the line `START_DAEMON="no"` to `START_DAEMON="yes"`
3. Then run:

   `sudo service fwknop-server stop`

   `sudo service fwknop-server start`

### 2. Warning admin on successful SPA (email, pushover script etc)

So, as stated above the current version present in Ubuntu repositories (2.6.0-2.1build1) cannot execute command on successful SPA. If you need this feature as of the OP, but it will be released at fwknop version (2.6.8), as can it is stated here:

https://github.com/mrash/fwknop/issues/172

So if you need to use it right now you can build from github branch master which have the `CMD_CYCLE_OPEN` option.

## 3. More resources on fwknop

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SinglePacketAuthorization

https://github.com/mrash/fwknop/ (project on GitHub)

http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/ (project site)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fwknop-to-enable-single-packet-authentication-on-ubuntu-12-04 (tutorial on DO's community)

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the OP. Also, you can implement a simple logwatcher as the following written in python3, which keeps reading for a file and executes a command when line contains pattern.

### `logwatcher.python3`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# follow.py
#
# Follow a file like tail -f.

import sys
import os
import time

def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfilename = sys.argv[1]
    pattern_string = sys.argv[2]
    command_to_execute = sys.argv[3]

    print("Log filename is: {}".format(logfilename))

    logfile = open(logfilename, "r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)

    for line in loglines:
        if pattern_string in line:
            os.system(command_to_execute)
```

### Usage

1. Make the above script executable:

`chmod +x logwatcher.python3`

2. Add a cronjob to start it after reboot

`crontab -e`

Then write this line there and save it after this:

`@reboot /home/YOURUSERNAME/logwatcher.python3 "/var/log/auth.log" "session opened for user" "/sbin/myscript.sh"`

The **first argument of this script is the log file to watch**, and the **second argument is the string for which to look** in it. The **third argument is the script to execute** when the line is found in file.

**It is best if you use something more reliable to start/restart the script in case it crashes.**

Comment: pattern_string should be used where startup_string is used? Can't edit myself